# yocto kernel module recipe

Tags: build, yocto, kernel-module, openembedded

I have a recipe as follows:

```
SUMMARY = "foo driver"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
inherit module
SRC_URI = "file://foo.tgz"
S = "${WORKDIR}/foo-module"

RPROVIDES_${PN} += "kernel-module-foo"
```

What I don't understand are:

1. There is no `do_compile()`, `do_install()`, `oe_runmake`...etc, why it will compile?
2. `RPROVIDES_${PN}` and `kernel-module-xxxx` can solve this issue if a kernel module needs to build?
3. Why there is no `FILES_${PN}` assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have `inherit module` in your recipe. This means you do have both `do_compile()` and `do_install()`: see meta/classes/module.bbclass.
2. You have not actually explained what your issue is?
3. *module* class inherits *kernel-module-split* class: this will create one package per built module, generating package names from module names, and setting FILES_* variables as needed. The `RPROVIDES` line seems to be just saying that one of the generated packages ("kernel-module-foo") can also be referred to with the name "${PN}".

See https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules for more details